# SSO login not working in iframe after chrome update

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, single-sign-on

I have an app that lists different in-house and third party apps. There are some apps that are opened in iframe within my app and some of them are SSO enabled. Recently after chrome update to version
84.0.4147.125 the SSO login stopped working for apps in iframe, its working fine when opened in a new browser window.

This behavior isn't occurring in any other browser except Chrome, can any one assist me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Root cause:

Certain cookies are set without the `SameSite` attribute.
They must be been blocked, as newer version of Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`

To validate this, you can set Chrome flag `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` as `Disabled`

[image: Chrome flag toggle for 'same site by default' setting]

#### Resolution:

- Specify `SameSite=None` and `Secure` if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
- Specify `SameSite=Strict` or `SameSite=Lax` if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests

Comment: This was the problem in my case - one domain was including (iframe) a login form from another, which, when the user was logged in, redirected him (still in iframe) to a third domain. Chrome rejected the cookies from the third domain, and the user was redirected back to the original login form with the message that the credentials were incorrect.

Comment: Yes, without any problems. Though, in order to be able to make it work for everyone using that login form (instead of just myself), I had to forgo this solution, and make some changes to my code.